# How to prevent user from bypassing php authentication

Tags: php, html, mysql, authentication

We call it html1 for simplicity.

When a user goes to html1, there's a login2.php login page to enable access to client.php which is the hidden page.

It then goes to checklogin.php...if the password and user name matches...it then goes to the hidden client.php page...if not..it goes back to homepage.

The user has to login to be able to view the contents of hidden client.php page.

However the user can access client.php by typing in ..../client.php on the address bar...therefore bypassing the auth page and rendering it useless.  I can just type  servername/client.php...and it still shows me the contents of client.php...but I want client.php...to be private!

**How do I prevent this from happening?**

thanks.

first login page...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Login Form</h2>
<table>
<form method="post" action="checklogin2.php">
<div id="name">User Id: <input type="text" name="****"></div>
<div id="password">Password: <input type="password" name="*******"></div>
<div class="button"><input type="submit" value="Login"></div>
</form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

then it goes to....
checklogin2.php

```
 <?php
    $*** = $_POST['****'];
    $***** = $_POST['***'];

if($uid == '****' and $***** == '*****')
{
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['sid']=session_id();
        header("location:securepage.php");
}


else
        {
                header("location:index.html");
        }
?>
```

Then it goes to...
securepage.php

```
<?php
        session_start();
        if($_SESSION['sid']==session_id())
        {

 header("location:client.php");

                echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
        }
        else
        {
                header("location:login.php");
        }
?>
```

Comment: You must have check at the top of every .php page. P.S. put session_start() at the top of the every page, too...

Comment: Thanks, I've put in session_start() at the top of my php page but doesn't seem to do anything?  I can still access client.php without logging in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the beginning of your every page you have to check if user is authorized.

On `checklogin.php` if user entered correct login and password, just set something like

```
$_SESSION['authorized'] = TRUE;
```

...and on other pages just check if user is authorized:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['authorized']) && $_SESSION['authorized'] === TRUE) {
    // Alright, let's show all the hidden functionality!
    echo "Psst! Hey! Wanna buy some weed?";
} else {
    // User is not authorized!
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit();
}
```

Note that you don't have to mess with cookies, session IDs etc. - just add `session_start()` before everything and freely use `$_SESSION` var.

This is the main pro of sessions (and `$_SESSION` variable in particular): you can **remember some data among different pages on same website.**

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  Would this work on just one page?  The rest of the pages are public...I just want one page to be private unless a user logs in.

Comment: Hi could you give me an example with my code?  I'm struggling to make clients.php private to everyone except a logged in user.

I can easily log myself out...type in clients.php in the address bar and view its contents without logging in!  I don't want this to happen.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

All pages has to check if the user is authed. I would recommend using objects, and always inherit a class that checks this for you. It's not fun to have the same code everywhere, doing the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  All pages?  Would this work on just one page?  The rest of the pages are public...I just want one page to be private unless a user logs in.

Comment: OK then you don't have to have the auth check on the public pages. I did not get that from your question. If you check the session variables I cannot see why it would matter if you got to path/path/client.php or ../../client.php.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The login/logout works...but even if the user is logged out...the user can still go to client.php just by typing it in the address bar.

I logged myself out...typed in client.php...and could access it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] == '/yourpagefolder/yourpage.php' && !isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
    header('location: login.php');
}
```

Comment: The above code works perfectly on a local server as it directs them back to the index if a successful session is not started; However, I had challenges on my live server as it doesn't seem to adhere to this principle. Hope it's helpful in your case though....